# Getting row id in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a data table which I retrieved from MySQL table. Before begin delete action for each row I want to give alert when delete button is pressed after selection of row. this is my java script code.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        var name = $('td', this).eq(0).text();
        $('#btnDeleteRow').click(function(e) {
            alert('You are going to delete ' + name + '\'s row');
        });
    });
});
```

It works. But the problem is I want only the last clicked row id to alert. My code gives all the row ids' i have clicked before I refresh the page. As I am new to jQuery please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to have a single click handler with a closure variable

```js
$(function() {
  var name;
  $('#dataTables-example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    name = $('td', this).eq(0).text();
  });
  $('#btnDeleteRow').click(function(e) {
    if (!name) {
      return
    }
    alert('You are going to delete ' + name + '\'s row');
    name = undefined;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnDeleteRow">Delete</button>
<table id="dataTables-example">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```